# Registry - How to rename key in registry using C++?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, registry

**How to rename key in registry using C++?**

I want rename key "Myapp\Version1" to "Myapp\Version2".

I don't see any function in MSDN about renaming keys in registry.

Comment: What you could do is store the version string in the registry under MyApp. Then, instead of renaming or copying & deleting you would just have to update the value of the version string.

Comment: [RegRenameKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regrenamekey)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no function to rename on older versions of windows, you need to copy/delete on your own AFAIK.

Answer (score 7):

If your app requires Vista or newer versions of Windows, you can use [RegCopyTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379768%28VS.85%29.aspx)() followed by [RegDeleteTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379776%28VS.85%29.aspx)().

Comment: Thanks Ferruccio, I will implement that :)

Answer (score 4):

Some more info on this old entry:

[NTRenameKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512138(v=vs.85).aspx) is an old API for renaming a registry key.

Also, [Pavel](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2015/09/29/regrenamekey-hidden-registry-api/) has more information on the RegRenameKey() call mentioned in randomsock's answer, and (though this is a C++ question) provides this nice PInvoke signature for it.

```
[DllImport("advapi32")]
public static extern int RegRenameKey(
     SafeRegistryHandle hKey,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string oldname,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string newname);
```

Comment: Updated URL for Pavel's post: [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200108004318/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2015/09/29/regrenamekey-hidden-registry-api/)

Answer (score 3):

if you need to support XP, could use [SHCopyKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) followed by [RegDeleteKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724847%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: `RegDeleteKeyEx` is not available on 32-bit XP. In there you have only one option, i.e. to use `RegDeleteKey`

Answer (score 3):

In case that someone needs the details about the renaming, I leave a log here.

The undocumented `RegRenameKey` is apparently defined:

```
LSTATUS WINAPI RegRenameKey( 
  _In_         HKEY    hKey, 
  _In_         LPCTSTR lpSubKeyName,
  _In_         LPCTSTR lpNewKeyName 
);
```

There is even a catch.  The first `lpSubKeyName` is the **key with path**.  However, the `lpNewKeyName` is only a new **name without path**.

**Edit-24.06.22022:**

Apparently Microsoft finally, after many years, decided it is a good idea to have this functionality documented.  You can find the documentation: [`RegRenameKey function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regrenamekey) (curtesy of Dirk Vollmar who noticed it)

Comment: You don't really need the full path, if handle is a handle of containing folder. Consider:
      string rootPath = "Software\\7-Zip";
      string OldName = "fff";
      string NewName = "aaa";

      RegistryKey rootKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(rootPath, true);
      int hResult = RegRenameKey(rootKey.Handle, OldName, NewName);

Comment: @Max thank you for your comment and example.  I did not write full path.  I wrote "key with path", which still fits your examples.

Comment: FYI, the `RegRenameKey` function nowadays _is_ documented, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regrenamekey

Comment: @DirkVollmar ah finally, it took them years. Thank you for the update, I'll edit the answer later on.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old entry, but in case anyone else comes looking, like me ...

In [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx), someone found an undocumented `RegRenameKey(hKey, keyName, newKeyName)` available from Vista onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Good day my fellow programmers,

Just in case you're trying to do it in C# (P/INVOKE), here is how I did it:

```
    public static readonly IntPtr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = new IntPtr(unchecked((int)0x80000002));

    [Flags]
    public enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
    {
        DELETE = 0x00010000,
        READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000,
        WRITE_DAC = 0x00040000,
        WRITE_OWNER = 0x00080000,
        SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000,
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000,
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000,
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE = 0x00020000,
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE = 0x00020000,
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x001F0000,
        SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x0000FFFF,
        ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY = 0x01000000,
        MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x02000000,
        GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000,
        GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000,
        GENERIC_EXECUTE = 0x20000000,
        GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum REGSAM : uint
    {
        DELETE = 0x00010000,
        READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000,
        WRITE_DAC = 0x00040000,
        WRITE_OWNER = 0x00080000,
        KEY_QUERY_VALUE = 0x0001,
        KEY_SET_VALUE = 0x0002,
        KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY = 0x0004,
        KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS = 0x0008,
        KEY_NOTIFY = 0x0010,
        KEY_CREATE_LINK = 0x0020,
        KEY_WOW64_32KEY = 0x0200,
        KEY_WOW64_64KEY = 0x0100,
        KEY_WOW64_RES = 0x0300,
        KEY_READ = (ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS | KEY_NOTIFY) & (~ACCESS_MASK.SYNCHRONIZE),
        KEY_WRITE = (ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE | KEY_SET_VALUE | KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY) & (~ACCESS_MASK.SYNCHRONIZE),
        KEY_EXECUTE = (KEY_READ) & (~ACCESS_MASK.SYNCHRONIZE),
        KEY_ALL_ACCESS = (ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL | KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_SET_VALUE | KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY | KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS | KEY_NOTIFY | KEY_CREATE_LINK) & (~ACCESS_MASK.SYNCHRONIZE),
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int RegCloseKey(
        IntPtr hKey);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(
        IntPtr hKey,
        string subKey,
        uint ulOptions,
        REGSAM samDesired,
        out IntPtr hkResult);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
    static extern int NtRenameKey(
        IntPtr KeyHandle,
        ref UNICODE_STRING NewName);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct UNICODE_STRING
    {
        public ushort Length;
        public ushort MaximumLength;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string Buffer;

        public UNICODE_STRING(string value)
        {
            int len = value.Length;
            Length = (ushort) (2 * len);
            MaximumLength = (ushort) (2 * (len + 1));
            Buffer = value;
        }
    }

    public static bool RenameHklmKey(string key, string newName)
    {
        IntPtr keyHandle;
        UNICODE_STRING unicodeString = new UNICODE_STRING(newName);
        int result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key, 0, REGSAM.KEY_ALL_ACCESS, out keyHandle);
        if (0 == result)
        {
            result = NtRenameKey(keyHandle, ref unicodeString);
            RegCloseKey(keyHandle);
        }

        return 0 == result;
    }
```

enums were taken from [Vanara project](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara)
Hope it helps someone